# How to prevent freeze at long operations

Tags: java, android

In VB.NET i can execute code like this:

```
Sub Compute(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handle btnCompute.Click
 For i = 0 to IterationLimit
  ' Do something
  Applicaton.DoEvents()
 Next
End Sub
```

One iteration run approximately 50 ms, but whole method run - about 5 minutes. "Appliction.DoEvents()" allow system to correctly refresh form and allow user to perform action (press button Cancel, stroke hotkey etc). How I can something like in java for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run the code in a thread if you want the UI and other components to remain responsive while it runs.

See this documentation for a very simple and clear example of how to run a method from a thread: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Basically you want to extend the `Thread` class:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        //do some background work
        //put whatever you want your thread to do here
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
new MyThread().start();
```

Answer (score 2):

For longer operations that might take a while to process, there are several ways to do this:

- Use a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) (IntentService - which is a subclass of Service should be fine). You can always get results when a service has completed doing the long operation in the background.
- Use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - this also runs in the background and although it is recommended for shorter operations like preparing UI elements, reading data from databases, files etc, you can do a bit of work to avoid freezing the UI thread.
- Creating a [Thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) subclass should also work just fine as mentioned in the answer by @nhouser9.

The goal is to avoid overworking the UI thread and negatively affecting the user experience.

I hope this helps.